# Get ERROR - Missing google_app_id, Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: google-analytics, flutter

While using google analytics with flutter, Get

> Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See "https://goo
>   .gl/NAOOOI"

I tried many things but this issue is not gone. I used

```
"apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"
```

in my android.build.gradle file also.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your problem and possibly show the relevant part of your flutter code.

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

The following instructions are no longer available as they have been replaced with https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start which use the `flutterfire configure` command to automatically add the needed dependencies.

build.gradle
[image: build.gradle]

app/build.gradle
[image: app/build.gradle]

---

Did you also add in the classpath and implementation parts as per the instructions?

[image: Required dependencies]

Comment: What instruction do you have in mind? I have followed this https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android and there's nothing like that mentioned.

Comment: Actually, this was the old instructions which are no longer available https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview/

Answer (score 1):

My project was using older version of flutter admob plugin and `google-services.json` file. The new Admob plugin expects the `admob_app_id` key-value pair to be present in the json file.

I solved this issue by downloading the new `google-services.json` file and replacing the old one with the newly downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

if you configured firebase using flutterfire_cli you need to configure each time when you add a new package to the project

1. flutter pub add firebase_analytics
2. flutterfire configure

[you can look in the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)

Answer (score 0):

I have just opened the analytics dashboard in the Firebase Console to make sure it is not disabled and found everything is okay, after that I stopped the app and made a fresh run and found that the error gone.